# CreateJS colorize black&white sprite

Tags: sprite, createjs

How can I do this?

I tried this, but has no effect

```
     var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        framerate: 60,
        "images": [loader.getResult("ball")],
        "frames": {"regX": 32, "height": 64, "regY": 32, "width": 64},
        // define two animations, run (loops, 1.5x speed) and jump (returns to run):
        "animations": {
            "run": [0, 63, "run", 1.5]
        }
    });
    ball = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet,"run")
    ball.x = 50;
    ball.y = 50;
    ball.filters = [
        new createjs.ColorFilter(0,1,1,1, 0,0, 0,0) // has no effect
    ];
    stage.addChild(ball);
```

stackoverflow wants me to post more details before I can post this

Image is black and white and I want to colorize it as in I want to drop red channel so RGB(155,155,155) becomes RGB(0,155,155)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to [cache](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Filter.html). So for example if `ball` is `100x100` then you could use this code:

```
ball = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet,"run")
ball.x = 50;
ball.y = 50;
ball.filters = [
    new createjs.ColorFilter(0,1,1,1, 0,0, 0,0) // has no effect
];
ball.cache(0,0, 100, 100);
stage.addChild(ball);
```